# Android app closes immediately after opening

Tags: java, android, git, runtime-error

After installing app on device, app is closing immediately after opening it .

I am learning android through Udacity. In lesson 3 they gave me android code with 
minimum layout.[Udacity code][1]. so they told to develop full code that displays Magnitude location and date in a Adapter view format.

Studio is not showing any errors but if i place cursor on **getMagnitude()** method It is showing method invocation **getMagnitude** may produce '**java.lang.NullPointerException**' and for setAdapter also it is showing same thing and My complete code is hear

```
EarthquakeActivity.java




/*``
 * Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.example.android.quakereport;
import java.lang.String;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

        // Create a fake list of earthquake locations.
        ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();
        earthquakes.add(new Earthquake("7.2","San Francisco", "Feb 2,2017 "));
        earthquakes.add(new Earthquake("5.2","London", "Oct 2,2017 "));
        earthquakes.add(new Earthquake("9.2","Tokyo", "Feb 2,2017 "));
        earthquakes.add(new Earthquake("8.2","Mexico City", "Mar 2,2017 "));
        earthquakes.add(new Earthquake("7.2","Mascow", "Feb 16,2017 "));
        earthquakes.add(new Earthquake("6.2","Rio de Jeneiro", "Feb 28,2017 "));
        earthquakes.add(new Earthquake("1.2","India", "Jan 2,2017 "));


        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
  EarthquakeAdapter adapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(this ,earthquakes);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Earthquake.java

```
package com.example.android.quakereport;

/**
 * Created by raghavendra on 3/7/2017.
 */

public class Earthquake {


    private  String mMagnitude;

    private String mLocation;

    private String mDate;


    public Earthquake(String Magnitude, String Location, String Date)
    {
        mMagnitude = Magnitude;

        mLocation = Location;

        mDate = Date;

    }

    public String getMagnitude()
    {

        return mMagnitude;
    }

    public String getLocation()
    {

        return mLocation;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {

        return mDate;
    }




}
```

EarthquakeAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.quakereport;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by raghavendra on 3/7/2017.
 */

public class EarthquakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Earthquake> {

    public EarthquakeAdapter(Context context, List<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
        super(context, 0, earthquakes);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.earthquake_activity, parent, false);
        }

        Earthquake currentEarthquake = getItem(position);



        TextView magnitudeView  = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);

        magnitudeView.setText(currentEarthquake.getMagnitude());

        TextView locationView  = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location);

        locationView.setText(currentEarthquake.getLocation());

        TextView dateView  = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);

       dateView.setText(currentEarthquake.getDate());






return listItemView;



    }

}








  [1]: https://github.com/udacity/ud843-QuakeReport
```

Comment: plz anybody  find out the problem .

Comment: please post error log

Comment: There is no getMagnitude in the code you uploaded. It's just the starting point branch of the course. Please push your changes.

Comment: Your variables names should be in camelCase. 

public Earthquake(String magnitude, String location, String date)
    {
        mMagnitude = magnitude;

        mLocation = location;

        mDate = date;

    }

Comment: @GustavoConde camelCase is a matter of personal taste. It doesn't affect the app performance by any means.

Comment: @Rotwang it will not solve the problem but it's part of the good practices. Good thing to know when you are starting in Android development.

Comment: @GustavoConde It's just a convention like tens of other ones. May like it or not, use it or not. It makes no real difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your Earthquake.java

try;

```
public class Earthquake {


    private  String mMagnitude;

    private String mLocation;

    private String mDate;


    public Earthquake(String Magnitude, String Location, String Date)
    {
        this.mMagnitude = Magnitude;

        this.mLocation = Location;

        this.mDate = Date;

    }

    public String getMagnitude()
    {

        return mMagnitude;
    }

    public String getLocation()
    {

        return mLocation;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {

        return mDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Earthquake class has no default constructor. Therefore the mMagnitude could be null, you should set it to

```
private String mMagnitude = "";
```

or add a default constructor for the Earthquake class:

```
public Earthquake() {
    mMagnitude = "";
    ...
}
```